# Spring-Integration , Upload File to SFTP remote server - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, upload, sftp

In my SpringBoot application, I have used Spring Integration for uploading files to a remote SFTP server.
Below is the code snippet I have used to transfer file to SFTP server.

```
protected String transfer(String downloadDirectory) {
        File[] files = new File(downloadDirectory).listFiles();
        byte[] payload = null;
        String path = null;
        try {

            path = getSftpPath(downloadDirectory);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (files[i].isFile()) {
                    payload = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(files[i].toURI()));
                    gateway.upload(payload, files[i].getName(), path);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return path;
    }
```

The upload method declaration and MessageHandler is as follows

```
@MessagingGateway(asyncExecutor = "sftpAsync")
    public interface UploadGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
        void upload(@Payload byte[] file, @Header("filename") String filename, @Header("path") String path);
    }

 @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(expressionParser.parseExpression("headers['path']"));
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(msg -> (String) msg.getHeaders().get("filename"));
        handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        return handler;
    }
```

It works fine for uploading files to a remote SFTP server. But after couple of execution, it starts showing

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source)
```

`payload = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(files[i].toURI()));` is the line where it throws the above error message.

As per my understanding, I am reading entire file into byte array, hence I am getting this error. Since I need entire file to send to upload method ,I have followed byte[] approach.

I already checked below mentioned threads.

[Byte[] and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError reading file by bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505025/byte-and-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-reading-file-by-bits?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory when invoking Files.readAllBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983588/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-direct-buffer-memory-when-invoking-files-readallbyte)

but the upload method need entire file instead of stream of bytes or chunks of data (correct me if i am wrong).

So,any suggestions to avoid above issue is great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace this: 
`payload = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(files[i].toURI()));
gateway.upload(payload, files[i].getName(), path);`

For this:
`Path tempFile = Paths.get(files[i].toURI());
gateway.upload(tempFile.toFile());`

Comment: You need to work with an InputStream instead of array or entire blob that will sit in memory. It can be ByteArrayInputStream, FileInputStream, etc. Study the sftp adapter java docs to see which interfaces are available.